# ClassNotFoundException: No RObject is found to match class type of org.redisson.RedissonMap with codec type of org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Having problems to solve LiveObject raised exception, I try to reproduce problematic behavior based on Redisson test cases.

The minimal code I get to reproduce issue is this test case (mostly inspired from RedissonLiveObjectServiceTest.java):

```
public class LiveObjectTest {

    public static final String TEST_VALUE = "my test value";
    public static final Integer TEST_INTEGER = 30;

    private RedissonClient redisson;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach () {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer()
                .setAddress("http://127.0.0.1:6379");
        redisson = Redisson.create(config);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach () {

        redisson.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test LiveObject with collection")
    public void testLiveObjectMap () {

        // Use Live Objects service
        RLiveObjectService service = redisson.getLiveObjectService();
        service.registerClass(TestREntityWithMap.class);

        TestREntityWithMap createdObject = new TestREntityWithMap("testID2");
        createdObject = service.persist(createdObject);

        RMap<Integer, String> map = redisson.getMap("testMap");
        createdObject.setValue(map);

        map.put(TEST_INTEGER, TEST_VALUE);

        TestREntityWithMap updatedObject = service.get(TestREntityWithMap.class, "testID");

        // Fails here to access updatedObject.getValue()
        assertEquals(TEST_VALUE, updatedObject.getValue().get(TEST_INTEGER));
    }

    // Tested class
    @REntity
    public static class TestREntityWithMap implements Comparable<TestREntityWithMap> {

        @RId(generator = UUIDGenerator.class)
        private String name;

        private Map<Integer, String> value;

        public TestREntityWithMap (String name) {

            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        protected TestREntityWithMap () {

            super();
        }

        public String getName () {

            return name;
        }

        public void setName (String name) {

            this.name = name;
        }

        public  Map<Integer, String> getValue () {

            return value;
        }

        public  void setValue (Map<Integer, String> value) {

            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo (TestREntityWithMap o) {

            return name.compareTo(o.name);
        }

    }
}
```

This fails converting back the RedissonMap object to an RObject...
Should not it rather try to convert value property to standard java.util.Map ?

This looks like rather simple usage of the API, am I missing some point here ?

Here is my ObjectMapper setup for JsonJackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
    mapper.addMixIn(Throwable.class, JsonJacksonCodec.ThrowableMixIn.class);

    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: After trying various LiveObject approaches, I always get back to the same error when trying to accese listed elements in an object retrieved from LiveObjectService.  So It may look more like a configuration issue. I'm adding my ObjectMapper setup to the main post in case it helps...

Answer (score 2):

OK....
In case that helps anyone, switching from Redisson 3.8.2 to 3.9.1 solved the bug.
A few minor changes in API (RTopics, connection scheme...) but it is well worth it !

Answer (score 0):

As of now latest redisson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Latest Jackson jackson.version property is `2.11.2` for me

```
    <!-- faster JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Updating Eclipse references

```
eclipse:eclipse -U
```